# Was there a book about the creation of NT4?

Tags: nt4

Someone told me once there was a good novel around the story of the development of NT4.  Does anyone know about this novel, what was its name?

Comment: Cen's answer is the correct one, but it's not a novel.

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Comment: @pnuts Quit bumping **crap** onto the front page. VTC and move on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The title is [Show Stopper! The Breakneck Race to Create Windows NT and the Next Generation at Microsoft](http://www.gpascalzachary.com/showstopper__the_breakneck_race_to_create_windows_nt_and_the_next_generation_at__50101.htm). It's ISBN-10 is 0029356717.

Comment: Did you read it ? Would you recommend it ?

Comment: @Brian I've read it. It's well written, and interesting if you are interested in MS's development processes and the history of NT. It's not the greatest work of reporting on the developemnt process I've ver read, but worth looking at.

Comment: I took the liberty to add a link, to what I think is the author's page. That felt cleaner than promoting Amazon here ... Not sure if there's a policy.

Comment: excellent thanks - that rings a bell now - BY THE WAY any other good books that cover development events like this?

Comment: @Greg "The Soul Of A New Machine" is probably the the best of the genre. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Soul_of_a_New_Machine.